# react-datetime with typescript TS2769 error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-datetime

I am using `react-datetime` with a react typescript project. I got TS2769 compile eror"

```
      TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<DatetimepickerProps>): ReactDatetimeClass', gave the following error.
    Type '(inputDate: Moment) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventOrValueHandler<ChangeEvent<any>>'.
      Types of parameters 'inputDate' and 'event' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | Moment | ChangeEvent<any>' is not assignable to type 'Moment'.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Moment'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DatetimepickerProps, context?: any): ReactDatetimeClass', gave the following error.
    Type '(inputDate: Moment) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventOrValueHandler<ChangeEvent<any>>'.
```

Following is my code:

```
...

handleDateChange(inputdate: moment.Moment) {
    ....
}

<DateTime
 timeFormat={false}
 viewMode="days"
 closeOnSelect
 closeOnTab
 required
 onChange={this.handleDateChange}
/>
```

I am not sure how to declare the type correct to make it compile. Any can help ?

Comment: What are you returning from handleChangeDate?

Comment: Nothing got returned. Just update the local state of the component. @Remy

Comment: Then I think that might be your problem:  `Type '(inputDate: Moment) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventOrValueHandler<ChangeEvent<any>>'.` You can't assign void to type EventOrValueHandler<ChangeEvent<any>>'. <-- That's what you need to provide in place of handleDateChange (or return something onChange can handle)?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `handleDateChange` doesn't equal what's required by `onChange`:

```
onChange?: EventOrValueHandler<ChangeEvent<any>>;
```

which is of type:

```
type EventOrValueHandler<Event> = (event: Event | Moment | string) => void;
```

If you update your function to accommodate for this you should be good. Eg:

```
<Datetime
    timeFormat={false}
    viewMode="days"
    closeOnSelect
    onChange={
      (value: ChangeEvent | Moment | string) => {
        if ((value) && value as Moment)
          console.log("Do something with moment")
      }
    }
/>
```